# Maze with 'backtracking' stuck in loop (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, depth-first-search, backtracking, maze

I'm working on a project where I am supposed to generate and solve random mazes with DFS and backtracking. So far I have managed to mark single nodes as "visited", and they show up as "1" instead of "0" on the grid, yet when I try to run the "random neighbour selection"-algorithm below, the program only visits a few nodes and then stops. Sometimes it even loops back and forth between i.e coordinate (0, 2) and (0, 1). Any tips? Code:

```
    // Starting node. Set to "visited".
    node new_node{0, 0};
    set_as_visited(new_node);
    node_stack.push(new_node);
    
    // "visited_nodes" is the counter for visited nodes.
    if (visited_nodes < (rows * cols)) {

        int stack_x = node_stack.top().x;
        int stack_y = node_stack.top().y;

        std::vector<int> neighbour;

        int north_x = stack_x;
        int north_y = stack_y - 1;
        if (north_y > 0 && !is_visited(north_x, north_y)) {
            neighbour.push_back(0);
        }

        int east_x = stack_x + 1;
        int east_y = stack_y;
        if (east_x < (rows - 1) && !is_visited(east_x, east_y)) {
            neighbour.push_back(1);
        }

        int west_x = stack_x - 1;
        int west_y = stack_y;
        if (west_x > 0 && !is_visited(west_x, west_y)) {
            neighbour.push_back(2);
        }

        int south_x = stack_x;
        int south_y = stack_y + 1;
        if (south_y < (cols - 1) && !is_visited(south_x, south_y)) {
            neighbour.push_back(3);
        }


            if (!neighbour.empty()) {
                srand(time(nullptr));
                int random_neighbour = neighbour[rand() % neighbour.size()];
                node neighbour_to_add{};

                switch (random_neighbour) {
                    case 0: // North
                        neighbour_to_add.x = north_x;
                        neighbour_to_add.y = north_y;
                        break;
                    case 1: // East
                        neighbour_to_add.x = east_x;
                        neighbour_to_add.y = east_y;
                        break;
                    case 2: // West
                        neighbour_to_add.x = west_x;
                        neighbour_to_add.y = west_y;
                        break;
                    case 3: // South
                        neighbour_to_add.x = south_x;
                        neighbour_to_add.y = south_y;
                        break;
                }

                set_as_visited(neighbour_to_add);
                node_stack.push(neighbour_to_add);
            }
            else node_stack.pop();

    }
    draw_maze(grid);
```

Here is my node struct:

```
struct node {
        int x, y;
    };
```

This is what shows up on compile:

```
1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 

Process finished with exit code 0
```

When I try to throw my algorithm into a while-loop, nothing gets printed out at all. I'm not even sure the code is compiling by then. All I see is my working directory.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You have told the computer to make 0,0 visited, add 0,0 to the stack, and then look at the top node of the stack, pick a random neighbour, make it visited, add it to the stack, draw the maze, then stop. It seems like the computer has done that with no problems. Is that what you wanted the computer to do? Or perhaps did you want it to do something a bit different?

Comment: @user253751 I have tried putting the whole thing, even with draw_maze(grid), inside of a while-loop, but it doesn't seem to want to pick the next node from the top of the stack.

Comment: @user253751 I would like to create some kind of iterator that will fill the entire grid with 1's instead of 0's, but I can't seem to do this without accidentally putting it in a constant loop.

Comment: Well if you put the whole thing inside a while loop then it's creating a brand new stack for each iteration and putting 0,0 at the top of that stack. Is that what you want?

Comment: @user253751 Not really what I am trying to do. I make sure the stack and starting node is outside of the while-loop, and only the "if(visited_node < ...) { ... } draw_maze(grid)"-part is inside of the while loop. I am updating the top of the stack for each neighbour, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe it would help to print out the coordinates for each iteration. Then you could figure out why it was getting stuck

Comment: @user253751 Yeah, I'm going to try and recreate the maze and carefully go through each step now. Thanks!